# geom_label unable to handle text transparency

Tags: r, ggplot2, transparency

I want to plot data using `geom_label` to plot some text inside rectangles. I can't find how to add transparency (alpha) to my text. In fact, transparency seems to apply only to the filling color:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars), alpha=cyl))+ geom_label(fill="blue")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars), alpha=cyl)) + geom_text()
```

When I use `geom_text` instead, the alpha parameters works as expected:

[image]
Do you know a way to make the text inside the label also transparent when using geom_label? 
Thanks,

Comment: It should be possible to edit `GeomLabel$draw_panel` to make it accept alpha for the text, or perhaps to edit the ggplot object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using this brutal trick you can make it work. Just move `label` inside `geom_text`,
and make an empty long string for `geom_label`, this is hardly a "reproducible" solution though.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, alpha=cyl)) + 
  geom_label(label="                               ", fill="blue") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = rownames(mtcars)))
```

[image]

**Edit** by @agenis: we could first compute the length of blank spaces for each label so we adapt the box to the text

```
ggplot(mtcars %>% mutate(blank_label = strrep(" ", nchar(rownames(.))*2)), aes(wt, mpg, alpha=cyl)) + 
  geom_label(aes(label=blank_label), fill="blue") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = rownames(mtcars)))
```

(the `*2` is because I coulnd't get a font with fixed-width characters")

Comment: Yes, I see the trick, kind of a workaround but thanks. I added a little improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested edit, I was looking for something similar too!.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a real answer, but solves a similar problem that I was having: my labels were hiding datapoints, but transparency of the labels background wasn't doing it for me, so I finally found a workaround: using the function [`scales::alpha`](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/alpha.html) to change the color aesthetic:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(alpha = .5, color = alpha('black', .5))
```

[image: Labels over dots, but you can still see them clearly... or most of them]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!